# how to call a .net dll from delphi 5 to make use of the methods

Tags: c#, .net, windows, delphi, dll

I have a problem calling the idblue.dll from this page http://idblue.com/support/drivers-software I'm using Delphi 5 
I tried using loadlibrary and making a external call

Comment: Can you please post some of your code so we can see what you're actually doing?

Comment: What's the problem? Without any further details, I don't think anyone would be able to help you.

Comment: How are you going to use `LoadLibrary` to consume a managed .net DLL? `LoadLibrary` is for unmanaged DLLs.

Comment: Are you sure it's a .net dll - that would be pretty unusual for a driver or related interface utility.

Comment: @500 follow the link provided. Obviously the driver is a typical kernel mode driver but the user mode api is managed.

Answer (score 1):

`LoadLibrary` is used for consuming unmanaged libraries. You are trying to use a managed library.

It is possible to spin up a .net runtime and call in to it from unmanaged code, but this is pretty labour intensive. Better probably is to wrap the managed DLL in a way that makes it convenient to consume from Delphi. Options include:

1. Creating a managed DLL that exposes a COM interface.
2. Wrapping with a mixed mode C++/CLI assembly. This would expose a classic unmanaged DLL interface.
3. Using Robert Giesecke's UnmanagedExports, again to expose the wrapper as an unmanaged DLL interface.